# Null in context.Request

Tags: c#, null, httpcontext

How to allow null in `Context.Request`:

```
context.Response.Write(retrieveList(context.Request["SalCode"].ToString(null), context.Request["groupKeyword"].ToString(), context.Request["text"].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, [`Request["..."]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.item.aspx) already returns a `string`, so there is no need to call `ToString()` on it and thus no need to worry, at this stage, if it returns `null` (i.e. if the key is not present in the request).

Thus you can call e.g.

```
retrieveList(
    context.Request["SalCode"],
    context.Request["groupKeyword"],
    context.Request["text"]);
```

without worrying if any of the three are null.

You can then alter `retrieveList` to respond correctly if any of the inputs is null. For example, you could *return* null:

```
private string /*or whatever*/ retrieveList(
    string salCode, string groupKeyword, string text)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(salCode) ||
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupKeyword) ||
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then, note that `Response.Write` doesn't care if you give it a `null`, it just writes nothing, so you can keep the call to `Write` as above.

Alternatively, you could for example check the return value and write a message if it is `null`:

```
var list = retrieveList(
    context.Request["SalCode"],
    context.Request["groupKeyword"],
    context.Request["text"]));
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(list))
{
    context.Response.Write(list);
}
else
{
    context.Response.Write("Missing request parameter.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TYou didn't specify anything! Please add information, you even didn't specify the environment, the classes, or the general context in which this problem occurs. nor do we know what the signature of  retrieveList() is! This makes us very difficult to help you! How much would you like to answer the question, one of my colleagues faced once: 'This crap doesn't work!' ? (Yes, it is not even a question, but happened in a real life support situatiuon!)

<del>One thing I noted is that you use **T**oString() instead of **t**oString(), I assume that is a typo.</del> (edited, as it is clear that this is C#) Also, I don't know what .toString(null) means. Did you want to tell us that that statement causes the NullPointerException? In that case, you could have committed a bit more effort towards us to understand your question, e.g. by writing this down...

BTW, if that's the case, I'd say, this will solve your problem:

```
Object salCode = context.Request["SalCode"];
context.Response.Write(retrieveList(salCode==null?"":salCode.ToString(), context.Request["groupKeyword"].ToString(), context.Request["text"].ToString()));
```

**EDIT** I think (but have no means to test) that if the null is the problem, this would fix it. If however, the underlying code does not work properly with empty String specified, that should be checked in retrieveList() like this (pasted from referenced post):

```
private string retrieveList(string SalCode, string groupKeyword, string text)
{
    SqlConnection _sqlCon = default(SqlConnection);
    SqlCommand _sqlCom = default(SqlCommand);
    SqlDataReader _sqlReader = default(SqlDataReader);
    StringBuilder _sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<TokenInputJSON> _out = null;

    try
    {
        _sqlCon = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SalesianBlastConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        _sqlCom = new SqlCommand("getTokenInput", _sqlCon);
        _sqlCom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        _sqlCon.Open();

        //This is the edited part
        if(SalCode==null || SalCode.Equals("")) {
            _sqlCom.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@salCode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 4)).Value = SalCode;
        }
        //... continue with the other parts
```

**Quick check**: I just had an idea: use a constant value when calling retrieveList to find out if this is the problem:

```
context.Response.Write(retrieveList("enterAValidSalCodeHere", context.Request["groupKeyword"].ToString(), context.Request["text"].ToString()));
```

Comment: this is where my whole code lies and my problem its in C# (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12832385/webhandler-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object)

Comment: Oops, I mistakenly thought it was Java. I'll try to enhance my answer to be correct - though I didn't program in C# since a really long time... Hoewver, the problem is that the SalCode, which is used as a parameter to your query in retrieveList(), is null. Is that a valid working condition? How should your program work when SalCode does not contain a valid value?

Comment: You could also use the null coalescing operator (??) like this: `salCode.ToString() ?? ""` - which basically translates as "if salCode.ToString() is null, use "" "; although since you're not doing an assignment this might not work.

Comment: Edited my answer, please check if that works. Sadly, I could not test it, as I don't have access to Visual Studio anywhere near...

Comment: @Tim i tried it but the error says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: Hmmmm, just curious (I'm not entirely familiar with C# in this context): is the 'context' a valid object, or does it happen to be null?

Comment: @ppeterka I'm still trying your idea.

Comment: @ppeterka - In this case, I would expect context to be valid (it's an HttpContext object) as OP is implementing IHttpHandler - though it's possible it's null.  Which might indicate a larger problem.  Easy enough to add a null check on context at the start to find out.

Comment: @Tim: thanks for clarifying, I never coded anything network related in C#, that's why I'm a bit lost here, but I'm convinced that the problem is related to something along a lot more obvious lines.

Comment: @ppeterka - You're welcome. I agree - I think it might be something with context itself.

Comment: @ChristineS did the error change? Can you post the stack trace in the post?